# Use sed to replace a text and output to a new line and also print it

Tags: bash, sed

I need to change replace a text in a file and output  the whole text file with the changed text and also print it to the screen.

This is what I got:

```
sed 's/123/456/g' number > number123
```

This changes the text and outputs to the new file but it won't print to the terminal.

How do I get it so it prints the changed text file to the terminal in that one command.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to display the *entire* (changed) file on the screen, or only the changed line(s)?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do the following:

```
sed 's/123/456/g' number | tee number123
```

The command `tee` reads from standard input and writes to standard output and files.

Comment: You definitely don't need `tee` for this job.

Comment: @don_crissti how would you redirect stdout to a file and still have it printed on screen without using `tee`? I would be interested to see an alternative.

Comment: @Alexander, see [Stéphane's answer](/a/267116/112566).

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight, I saw it and it's a great alternative.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/123/456/g; w number123' number
```

Note that it prints (and writes in `number123`) all the lines, including those that didn't contain `123`.

To only print the modified ones:

```
sed -e 's/123/456/gw number123' -e t -e d number
```